# How Do I Edit a Nested Form Array using PatchValue?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, patchvalue

I have a service that calls an API to populate a select dropdown.  When I select an option my OnChange method retrieves data from another service that is being called. that data is then displayed on the UI.  The data displays fine, it's that if I want to change something the fields don't get updated.  Right now I'm using a push control inside of a forEach to get the data.

```
const infoTemp = this.tempInfo?.customFields?.textCustomFields;
    infoTemp.forEach((res) => {
      this.customNameFormArr.push(
        this.fb.group({
          name: [res.name],
          value: [res.value],
        })
      );
    });
```

I'm pretty sure that I have to use patchValue for me to be able to edit the fields.  I've tried this piece of code but it doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

```
    this.envelopeRequest.controls.newRequest.patchValue({
      customFields: {
        textFields: [
          {
            name: res.name,
            value: res.value
          }
        ]

        }
      })
```

Here is a link to my StackBlitz demo.  Thanks.[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fqouoq?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML, you are binding the value with the `value` attribute.

```
<input type="text" value="{{ t.value }}" />
```

Instead, you need to apply the `formControlName` attribute to utilize the Reactive Form (way), so it will reflect the value.

```
<input type="text" formControlName="value" />
```

For the second issue, I noticed that when changing the option, the `FormArray`(s) will retain the value from the previous (selected) option. You are not doing right in resetting/clearing the items in the `FormArray`(s) before binding with the value for the newly selected option.

```
this.customNameFormArr.clear();
this.customTextFormArr.clear();
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cjrn2t?file=src%2Fmain.ts)